# How to use recursion to round a decimal to the nth place

Tags: java, recursion

I have a comp sci question that requires the following:

Write a method that takes a decimal number `x` and an integer `n`. Round `x` to `n` decimal places (for example, `0` means round to the nearest integer, `1` means round to the nearest tenth, etc.).

I don't see how this problem is even approachable using recursion, it seems too straight forward.

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: If it seems too straight forward why not do it yourself?

Comment: Recursion involves a repeated action. There is no repeated action in rounding off, so the problem cannot be solved using recursion.

Comment: @CodeBlue Rounding is just a mathematical function. You can implement that function with recursion. Example: nullptr's answer. I think it may be worth bringing up the inherent deficiencies with rounding a base 10 number using binary representations though.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that using recursion here is simply counter-productive.

The recursive method [suggested by **nullptr**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16452726/732016):

```
double round(double x, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return Math.round(x);

    return round(x * 10, n - 1) / 10;
}
```

is valid, but unnecessary. Essentially, that method is the same as:

```
double round(double x, int n) {
    double factor = Math.pow(10, n);
    return Math.round(x * factor) / factor;
}
```

This method would likely execute faster and would not risk a `StackOverflowError` (although that would be fairly unlikely, only with huge values of `n`).

You should use recursion for cases with a clear **base case** and **simplification case**, such as:

- traversing a tree:

  - base case: no children
  - simplification case: each child
- the factorial function:

  - base case: `n <= 1`
  - simplification case: `factorial(n-1)`

Rounding to *n* decimal places does not lend itself to recursion easily.

---

BONUS: Rounding to the nearest *n* th-fractional part in any base:

```
double round(double x, int n, int radix) {
    double factor = Math.pow(radix, n);
    return Math.round(x * factor) / factor;
}
```

Comment: I think you actually want to multiply and then divide as in nullptr's answer. Otherwise, `round(3.1, 1) => .31 => 0 => 0`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
double round(double x, int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return Math.round(x);

    return round(x * 10, n - 1) / 10;
}
```

You'll have to adapt this a little if you can't use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 0):

i used recursion and parsing, however i think there are some logical holes.

```
public static double problem3(double x, int y)
{
    // Trying to take the double, turn it into a string, manipulate past the decimal
    // probably not the most efficient method..

    String P = Double.toString(x).substring(0, Double.toString(x).length()-1);
    String k =P.substring(P.indexOf('.')+ 1,P.length());


    if (k.length()==y)
    {
        if (P.charAt(P.length()-1)<5)
        {

        return Double.parseDouble(P);
        }
        else
        {double o7 = Double.parseDouble(P)*Math.pow(10, k.length());
        o7++;
        o7=o7/Math.pow(10, k.length());
            return o7;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return problem3(Double.parseDouble(P),y);
    }





}
```